# The empty path didn't match any of these. (Python3, Django, URLS)

Tags: django, python-3.x, url, view, ipython

I'm learning Python3. I installed python and django on my webserver.
But I have a problem with URLs.

Here's what I tried :

1. sctructure:

   ```
   expnk.ru
   HelloDjango (1)
     HelloDjango (2)
        setting.py
        ..........
        urls.py
     cat
     ...
     any apps
   ```
2. run "cat" from ssh command: 
   `python3 manage.py startapp cat`
3. next im going to HelloDjango (2) file and edited file `setting.py`, for `INSTALLED_APPS` and added `'cat'`
4. then I'm doing `HelloDjango (2) -> urls.py`. I added to this file the next strings:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cat/', include('cat.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^test/', include('test.urls')),
]
```

5. then I do: `cat -> urls.py` and add to this file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

6. lastly, I edited file `views`, code from this file is below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(response):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")

# Create your views here.
```

I created the cat application similar to the blog application, as a result: the blog is running, but cat is not.

Comment: cat is working fine, but you went to localhost:8000/ instead of localhost:8000/cat

Comment: im open django on webserver, not local web server. U can watch problem on url: expnk.ru

Comment: That's a strange thing to do if you are only in development, but irrelevant: exactly the same comment applies.

Comment: describe the problem, described, now I try to correctly interpret your answers
I'm not a developer, I'm interested in python + django and I want to learn it by solving practical problems.
Thank you for your comments, but I never solved the problem (

Comment: which version of Django?

Comment: expnk.ru/cat// works. So I think you have a "/" in your url, unlike what you show in the code above. Probably `url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index')`.

Comment: `django-admin.py version` display `2.1.5`

Comment: Thank u very much, deark dirkgroten! I think, im understand logic of urls in django... im hope:-)